# How do you override the html { min-width: 1200px } on wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to change my wordpress theme to be 860px wide instead of 1200px.  I have gotten all of the content to be 860px and the header/footer and it all looks great.  Even the `<html>` tag says that its 860px when I view it in firebug.

However, there is still CSS code in my `<head>` tag that I don't know where it's coming from and it puts in `html { min-width: 1200px; }`.  This causes my site to load as 1200px wide on mobile with the content only 860px wide.  So there is blank space to the right of all of my content.  I just want it 860px, not centered or anything else.  Any advice would help, thank you all!

Comment: cant help without code or a link. have you tried overriding that with `!important`?

Comment: Which wordpress theme you are using?

Comment: I just wonder what is another way for overriding other than `!important`

Comment: I am using the Dante theme by SwiftIdeas.  I have set the min-width, max-width, and width all to 860px !important and to no avail.

Comment: Worst approach. Remove this property with `jQuery`.

Comment: The white border on the right goes away if I set the theme to be "responsive", but I don't want the theme to be responsive as it just doesn't look right when I do this and it bumps down my sidebars and makes my pictures tiny

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't succeed in finding where it is coming from, You can add this style in ur css to override the `min-width` property :-

```
html { min-width: 860px !important; }
```

Jquery Approach :-
Paste this code at the end of your page, just before closing `</body>` tag :-

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("html").css("min-width", "");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new and never used jQuery, could you please give me a little guidance as how to do it with jQuery?  Where would i put this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling any add-ons and plugins until that rule stops loading in the `<head>`. Then you know where the culprit is.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i fixed this exact problem on a wordpress site of a friend.

The problem was at a div named with a class he had created inside a widget. This specific class had the min-height set. Like this.

```
<div class="deepest">
```

So it was stretching the whole template.

So I suggest searching for any divs you had created that have a class and delete the class name.

Good luck,

Bill.